# SBT dependency-tree

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to see the entire SBT tree, but when I run sbt dependency-tree, I do not receive any results (after a minute or so of processing).

How can this be resolved?

Thanks
Nir

Comment: What makes you think that  `dependency-tree` is an available task? Are you using any plugin for that?

Comment: dependency-tree is not an sbt command. Which sbt-plugins are you using?

Comment: we have the following plugins:

     addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.5.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.8.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-unidoc" % "0.3.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.8.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.timushev.sbt" % "sbt-updates" % "0.2.0")

Comment: Look at [dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph#main-tasks) tasks. Choose one and then tells us if it works

Comment: thanks. So I am trying to use dependencyTree in sbt, but after the processing, it's returning anything. Using dependencyBrowseGraph does return a result in thr browser, but we cannot find the dependency that we are looking for (hadoop-mapreduce-client) which seems to be retrieved with 2 different version on our project

Comment: Could you edit your question with the goal you want? Which in this case seems to be "How can I find the users of this dependency with SBT" ?

Comment: Try `show dependencyTree`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to show a nice dependency tree/graph of your build dependencies. In your `plugins.sbt` file, add the following line:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.9.2")
```

Then after that, do `sbt clean compile` for the plugin to take effect. Then in your terminal, execute `sbt dependencyTree` or any other command specified in [this link](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!